# cleanest way to modify a netcdf entry in xarray using nearest location and given time stamp

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I want to modify the value of a netcdf array at a given index which is the nearest array entry to my chosen lat/lon coordinate and for a given date.  I came up with the following solution using `xarray`'s `sel` and `loc` but the loc command seems very longwinded with all the "values", using the online [xarray manual](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125653/extracting-nearest-lat-lon-and-time-value-from-netcdf-using-xarray)

```
ds=xr.open_dataset("test1.nc")
idx=ds.sel(lon=0,lat=20,time="1951-03-15",method="nearest")
ds["sit"].loc[dict(lon=idx.coords["lon"].values,lat=idx.coords["lat"].values,time=idx.coords["time"].values)]=100
ds.to_netcdf("test2.nc")
```

Is there is a shorter, neater way to do this task?

Comment: You shouldn’t need to do that. Does `ds["sit"].loc[dict(lon=idx.lon,lat=idx.lat,time=idx.time)]=100` work? Or just `ds["sit"].loc[dict(idx[["lat", "lon", "time"]])]=100`

Comment: great!  The second simplest one I had already tried and it sets the array to 100 everywhere, but the first one works, thank you! if you post it I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass DataArrays for the dictionary values to [`xr.DataArray.loc`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing):

```py
ds["sit"].loc[dict(lon=idx.lon,lat=idx.lat,time=idx.time)] = 100
```