# Extract interpolated values from a 2D array based on a large set of xy points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, python-xarray

I have a reasonably large 1000 x 4000 pixel `xr.DataArray` returned from an [OpenDataCube](https://www.opendatacube.org/) query, and a large set (> 200,000) of `xy` point values. **I need to sample the array to return a value under each `xy` point, and return interpolated values** (e.g. if the point lands halfway between a `0` and a `1.0` pixel, the value returned should be `0.5`).

`xr.interp` lets me easily sample interpolated values, but it returns a huge matrix of every combination of all the `x` and `y` values, rather than just the values for each `xy` point itself. I've tried using `np.diagonal` to extract just the `xy` point values, but this is slow, very quickly runs into memory issues and feels inefficient given I still need to wait for every combination of values to be interpolated via `xr.interp`.

**Reproducible example**

(using just 10,000 sample points (ideally, I need something that can scale to > 200,000 or more):

```
# Create sample array
width, height = 1000, 4000
val_array = xr.DataArray(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(height, width)).astype(np.float32),
                         coords={'x': np.linspace(3000, 5000, width),
                                 'y': np.linspace(-3000, -5000, height)}, dims=['y', 'x'])

# Create sample points
n = 10000
x_points = np.random.randint(3000, 5000, size=n)
y_points = np.random.randint(-5000, -3000, size=n)
```

**Current approach**

```
%%timeit

# ATTEMPT 1
np.diagonal(val_array.interp(x=x_points, y=y_points).squeeze().values)
32.6 s ± 1.01 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Does anyone know of a faster or more memory efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To avoid the full grid, you need to introduce a new dimension.

```
x = xr.DataArray(x_points, dims='z')
y = xr.DataArray(y_points, dims='z')
val_array.interp(x=x, y=y)
```

Will give you an array just along the new z dimension:

```
<xarray.DataArray (z: 10000)>
array([4.368132, 2.139781, 5.693636, ..., 3.7505  , 3.713589, 2.28494 ])
Coordinates:
    x        (z) int64 4647 4471 4692 3942 3468 ... 3040 3993 3027 4427 3749
    y        (z) int64 -3744 -4074 -3634 -3289 -3221 ... -4195 -4131 -4814 -3362
Dimensions without coordinates: z

36.9 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

There's a nice example in the xarray docs on [Advanced Interpolation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html#advanced-interpolation).